# Web App Architecture

Tags: jquery, web-services, jsp, rest, architecture

I'm currently working with two entities:

- A JSP that uses jQuery
- A RESTful WebService that I use to query a database for a collection of Foo objects.

In the JSP, I make an AJAX call the WS that returns my collection, and I begin to iterate through it, with the intent of displaying some of each Foo's variables in a data table.  There's a business requirement that says, if Foo.bar is present, show it on the screen.  Otherwise, in the bar column, show the value of Foo.baz.  This, by my definition, is application-specific business logic.

My question:  where should this logic go?  I don't think it belongs in the WS, because I want myself and others to rely on this as your one-stop shop for getting raw Foo objects, not Foo objects that have had the above conditions applied to them.  I also don't think it belongs in the JSP, because it should only be a means by which to display data.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You said it yourself:

> There's a business requirement that says, if Foo.bar is present, **show it on the screen**. Otherwise, in the bar column, **show the value of Foo.baz**.

That sounds an awful lot like display logic, so I think the JSP is an appropriate place since it handles that layer of the application.

Comment: Here's a better example, perhaps.  All Foo objects come from the foo table.  Foo.bam is a numeric code.  The textual definition of that code is stored in the Codes table.  I need to display the text description of Foo.bam, not just the numeric code.  Where should that functionality "live"?

Comment: The data layer should be responsible for joining both tables and returning a result set where each row contains both the numeric code and the description. The display layer should receive both pieces of information and render them as appropriate. Does that make sense?